# cuDNN code sample compile error

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, cuda, nvidia, cudnn

I'm trying to install NVIDIA's cuDNN library and run their code sample, but it's giving me these errors and I don't know what is wrong.

```
make all 
Building target: cuDNNtest
Invoking: NVCC Linker
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/ -L".../cuda-workspace/cuDNNtest/FreeImage/lib/linux/x86_64" -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --relocatable-device-code=true -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -link -o  "cuDNNtest"  ./fp16_dev.o ./fp16_emu.o ./mnistCUDNN.o  ./UtilNPP/StopWatchLinux.o   -lcudnn -lFreeImage -lcublas
./mnistCUDNN.o: In function `npp::ImageAllocator<unsigned char, 1ul>::Malloc2D(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, bool)':
.../cuda-workspace/cuDNNtest/UtilNPP/ImageAllocatorsNPP.h:76: undefined reference to `nppiMalloc_8u_C1'
./mnistCUDNN.o: In function `npp::ImageAllocator<unsigned char, 1ul>::Free2D(unsigned char*)':
.../cuda-workspace/cuDNNtest/UtilNPP/ImageAllocatorsNPP.h:87: undefined reference to `nppiFree'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cuDNNtest] Error 1
```

I'm using Nsight Eclipse Edition on Linux centOS, cuda toolkit 7.5 and Titan X (compute capability 5.2, I think).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to add one more library to your command `-lnppi`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! I tried `-lnpp` before, but not that one.

Comment: @DanielaG: Would you mind adding a short answer explaining how you solved the problem for the next person with the same question?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this adding `-lnppi` to the libraries list in the project's properties.